# Show that is a smooth variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

can you check this exercise?
 Let $k$ be an algebraic closed field, and $X=V(x-yz,xz-y^2,y-z^2)\subset \mathbb A^3_k$. Show that $X$ is a smooth variety.

If $X=V(f,g,h)$, where 
$f=x-yz,g=xz-y^2,h=y-z^2$, then 
$f_x=1,f_y=-z,f_z=-y$
$g_x=z,g_y=-2y,g_z=x$
$h_x=0,h_y=1,g_z=-2z$

Thus the partial derivaties are nonzero for every $(x,y,z)$ and this shows that $X$
 is smooth.

Comment: @Ehsan M. Kermani the rank is 2 that is not 0. Therefore the origin is singular. I am confused!

Comment: In principle you must also check that the polynomials given generate the ideal $I(X)$.

Comment: @user1133057: the rank of the jacobian at **every** point of the curve is $2$, and this proves that **every** point of the curve is smooth. You say you are confused: maybe you misinterpret the jacobian criterion for smoothness?

Answer (score 4):

The ring of functions of the affine variety $X$ is  $\mathcal O(X)=\frac {k[x,y,z]}{(x-yz, xz-y^2, y-z^2)}$.
It is isomorphic to $k[z]$ *via* the isomorphism (of $k$-algebras)  $\mathcal O(X)\stackrel {\cong}{\to}   k[z]$ sending $\bar x\mapsto z^3, \bar y\mapsto z^2, \bar z\mapsto z$ .
From the isomorphism of rings $\mathcal O(X) \cong k[z]$, we  deduce that the affine variety $X$ is isomorphic to the affine variety $\mathbb A^1_k$, and $X$ is thus definitely smooth.
Note that $X$ can also be seen as the image of the embedding $$ \mathbb A^1_k \hookrightarrow   \mathbb A^3_k :t \mapsto (x,y,z)=(t^3,t^2,t)          $$

**Edit**
Since there seems to be some misunderstanding on this thread, let me try to clarify:
The jacobian of the morphism $$Jac(f):\mathbb A^3_k \to  \mathbb A^3_k: (x,y,z)\mapsto (x-yz,xz-y^2,y-z^2)$$ is $$Jac(f)=  \begin {pmatrix} 1&-z&-y\\z&-2y&x\\0&1&-2z   \end {pmatrix}        $$It has rank **2** at every point **on the curve**:
Indeed $\operatorname {det} Jac(f)=0$ on the curve but  the minor $det \begin {pmatrix} 
1& -z \\ 0 & 1 \end {pmatrix}$ obtained from lines $1,3$ and columns $1,2$ of $Jac(f)$ is non-zero.
We may then apply  the jacobian criterion for proving smoothness of $X$  .